# Save excel file with custom ribbon, and module code?

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to find a way to save a workbook with a custom ribbon, and with the module code for the ribbon items.

The way I save my new workbook is as follows:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & "\" & strNewFileName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

The workbook is saved just as I would like but without the ribbon, and module code. What I am doing is pretty much copying everything in the existing workbook, and creating a new workbook within the same directory. Can you save the ribbon from one workbook to a new workbook?

Comment: SaveAs should save your ribbon and code into a new book without problems. The only issue I see in your code is the use of Activeworkbook. It's a risk if you have several books open at the same time - you might be saving the wrong one. Replace Activeworkbook with Thisworkbook, or better yet - with an explicit reference to the book you want to save (i.e, Workbooks("My Book with Code").SaveAs etc)

Comment: @Rado thank you, I am sure that is my issue. Noob mistake....